# Python: PyAutoGui click location is off by a few pixels when using an image to locate

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

**Goal of the program:** open a web browser tab to youtube, use a saved image of the "Youtube" button on the Youtube home screen to move the mouse position to that location, do a mouse click when there

**Issue:** The mouse moves to a location that is off by a few pixels (-29 x, -35 y) when performing the click() step. The coordinates are correct at the time of locateCenterOnScreen but are different when it does click()

**What I've tried:** I had the program print out the coordinates of the picture when it takes it's location and at that point in time the coordinates are correct, I used a mouse position program to narrow down how much its off by.

**My Question:** What is causing the position of the click() to be offset by these few pixels and how do I fix it?

```
import pyautogui as auto
import webbrowser
import time


site = "https://www.youtube.com/"
webbrowser.open_new_tab(site)
time.sleep(5)
x, y = auto.locateCenterOnScreen('test.png')
print(x)
print(y)
try:
    auto.click(x,y)
except:
    print("Not Found")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-taking the picture I used for the program to locate and it works now. I'm unsure why the original one did not work as intended though.

Answer (score 0):

probably your window was resized so the widht and height of the image you where looking for also changed.
I recommend using:

```
win = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('windownname')[0]
win.size = (1600, 900)
```

to resize a window